# How to set special permission on user registration using Djoser in Django REST Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, registration, user-permissions, djoser

I'm using Djoser and I need only admins to be able to register new users.

I set in global settings this permission classes:

```
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly',
],
```

so admins can edit, users can see, others can nothing.

But this rule doesn't share on the Djoser registration module which is on POST auth/users. How to setup special permission rule for it?

Comment: Create custom permissions, Django can handle this, DRF can handle it too

Comment: The problem was how and where to create them.

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how to ask. Research well before asking

Comment: Could you please highlight the mistakes that you pointed out in my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: in DJOSER settings is PERMISSIONS field which allows to setting some user actions - more info [here](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#permissions)